# How can I convert Pair to 2 dimensional array in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a simpler approach by which I can convert [Pair](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Pair.html) to 2 dimensional array?

Here is what I have tried:

```
public int[][] func() {
      List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();

      //this is example value
      pairs.add(new Pair<>(1,2));
      pairs.add(new Pair<>(2,3));
      pairs.add(new Pair<>(3,4));

      //I want to make array same size of pair's
      int[][] arr = new int[pairs.size()][2];

      for(int i =0 ; i < pairs.size(); i++) {
          arr[i][0] = pairs.get(i).getKey();
          arr[i][1] = pairs.get(i).getValue();
      }

      return arr;
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `Stream`s:

```
int[][] arr = pairs.stream()
                   .map(pair -> new int[] {pair.getKey(),pair.getValue()})
                   .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

BTW, instead of using a javafx `Pair` class, perhaps it would be better to use the more standard `java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` class.

Comment: why are you suggesting to use `SimpleEntry` instead of `Pair`? What is the reason? Thanks

Comment: @Leviand I'd always prefer using core Java classes (i.e. java.*) instead of classes of external packages (unless you are using javafx anyway).

Comment: If I'm not wrong, I think that javafx is bundled with JRE8 and JDK8: in this case, do you still see any other reasons to prefer `SimpleEntry`?

Comment: @Leviand I guess it's a matter of opinion. When I have two classes that do the same thing, I prefer to use the one in the more basic package / library. java.* is more basic than javafx.*. Even within java.*, I'd prefer to use java.lang.* or java.util.* classes over, say, java.net.* or java.sql.* classes